# Sass output error in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: css, sass

I installed Sass via Chocolatey and get this error in the Netbeans console:

"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sass\tools\sass.bat" "--cache-location" "C:\Users\oxk4r\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\sass-compiler" "--debug-info" "--style" "compact" "C:\xampp\htdocs\SASS_01\scss\style.scss" "C:\xampp\htdocs\SASS_01\css\style.css" Could not find an option named "cache-location".

No *.css file is generated at all.

Comment: For Linux, see [How to use Sass 1.14 with NetBeans 8.2 on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757589/how-to-use-sass-1-14-with-netbeans-8-2-on-linux)

Comment: This is for Windows. Take a look at the paths.

Comment: Hence a comment and no answer

Comment: I had the same problem using the Sass standalone version, but Christopher's helps out in this case, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Sass install directory, in file sass.bat, after the command:

```
set arguments=%*
```

add the following (replace username with your windows username)...

```
set arguments=%arguments:--cache-location =%
set arguments=%arguments:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\sass-compiler =%
set arguments=%arguments:--debug-info =%
```

This strips out all of the arguments that are no longer accepted.

Comment: Also resolves the problem if you installed Sass using the standalone version.

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer time after time. Thank you.

Comment: Also change the folder name that is the Netbeans version number after Cache if you install new version of Netbeans

Answer (score 4):

I copy here the answer of Pete Whelpton at Apache Netbeans bug tracking for future reference because it is very useful for this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2347

> Netbeans SASS support was written for the original Ruby SASS.  Modern
> SASS implementations (Dart SASS et al) are based on libsass.
>
> There is very limited/incomplete support for libsass already in
> Netbeans (command line flags are NOT supported - but it should
> compile).  To implement the workaround:
>
> 1. Open your netbeans.conf file (/etc/netbeans.conf in the NB
>    installation folder)
> 2. Add the following to the
>    netbeans_default_options parameter: -J-Dnb.sass.libsass=true
> 3. Launch Netbeans, Tools -> Options -> HTML5/JS -> CSS PreProcessors and
>    configure it to point to your libsass implementation (e.g. the
>    sass.bat file in your dart-sass installation folder)

In my case (Apache Netbeans Windows 64) this workaround worked.

Answer (score 1):

for Windows you may to edit sass.bat file.

In file need in variable `arguments` to replace a substring `"--debug-info"`  and (for example) `"--cache-location C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\sass-compiler"` on empty data

for example:

`SET repaire_arguments=%arguments:--debug-info=%
SET repaire_arguments=%repaire_arguments:--cache-location C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\sass-compiler=%
"%SCRIPTPATH%\src\dart.exe" "-Dversion=1.16.1" "%SCRIPTPATH%\src\sass.dart.snapshot" %repaire_arguments%`

Answer (score 0):

When I had that error my installation wasn't working correctly. 
I didn't use Chocolatey though. I installed ruby and sass with gem, added the path in the config and got it working. Maybe that helps.

Comment: When using ruby sass gem you get a message to say it is no longer supported