# How to sanitaze args in node-sass cmd file in order to let Netbean 10 work

Tags: netbeans, sass

I'm using the `node-sass` version.

Netbeans has a very old bug about Sass compiling adding `--cache-location` argument while this doesn't exist anymore since many years. This bug was fixed in Netbean 8.1 but.... reintroduced in 8.2 and still alive in 10.0 (WOW!).

There are many work-around in order to skip the issue by editing the ".bat" file used by Sass and sanitize the arguments just before they can reach the real sass.
Good example are:

https://gist.github.com/Caffe1neAdd1ct/59356d981e6fa33ddb1f

[Sass output error in Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651226/sass-output-error-in-netbeans-8-2)

However I can find any script for a `node-sass` implementation anywhere.
I guess it's easy but I don't have expertise in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a script that seems to work.
I create a bat file that wrap the cmd file.
I know this is silly but works.

Here the `sass.bat` file

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO TEST ME
set arguments=%*
set arguments=%arguments:--cache-location =%
set arguments=%arguments:C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\sass-compiler =%
set arguments=%arguments:--debug-info =%
ECHO %arguments%
"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd" %arguments%
```

just change USERNAME to yours and should fix the issue with SASS in Netbean